# ASP.NET MVC Sitemap provider - non-dynamic node under dynamic node

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a dynamic node provider which is copied below along with my site map configuration.  When I go to my url, /Account/Edit/1475, the breadcrumb shows "Home > Accounts > [Incorrect Account Name] > Edit".  It is showing an account name that is different then the 'accountId' in the url, 1475.  I assume it is due to the 'preservedRouteParameter=accountId' that is causing it to match the wrong node. Is this right?

Do I need to create another DynamicNodeProvider for the Account Edit node in my sitemap? I started going down this path, but I needed to create a separate Dynamic Node Providers for most of the nodes so I thought I must be doing something wrong.  Is there something I am missing in the configuration?

```
public class AccountDynamicNodeProvider : DynamicNodeProviderBase
{
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node)
    {
        using (var entities = new Entities())
        {
            foreach (var account in entities.TAccounts)
            {
                var dynamicNode = new DynamicNode("Account_" + account.AccountId, account.AccountName);
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("accountId", account.AccountId);

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Accounts" controller="Account" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Detail" controller="Account" action="Details" dynamicNodeProvider="my.test.namespace.AccountDynamicNodeProvider, my.assembly">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Edit" controller="Account" action="Edit" preservedRouteParameters="accountId" />
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

This is the route that is being used:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "Account",
  url: "Account/{action}/{accountId}",
  defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Details" }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [SiteMapTitleAttribute](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Using-Action-Filter-Attributes#sitemaptitle) to dynamically change the title when using preservedRouteParameters.

```
[SiteMapTitle("MyTitle", Target = AttributeTarget.ParentNode)]
public ViewResult Edit(int accountId) { 
   var account = _repository.Find(accountId);

   // MyTitle is a string property of 
   // the account model object.
   return View(account); 
}
```

Or

```
[SiteMapTitle("MyTitle", Target = AttributeTarget.ParentNode)]
public ViewResult Edit(int accountId) { 
   ViewData["MyTitle"] = "This will be the title";

   var account = _repository.Find(accountId);
   return View(account); 
}
```

In general, when configuring CRUD operations it is best to use preservedRouteParameters all the way. But going that route comes with the caveat that you need to fix the title and node visibility manually.

CRUD operations (other than perhaps Add New) generally don't appear in the Menu or SiteMap, instead a list or table is usually made on the page to dynamically generate commands for each record. So the only thing you typically have to worry about is the SiteMapPath, and for that you can use preservedRouteParameters.

Have a look at the Forcing a Match demo in [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position).